# How to change the input type from text to date?

Tags: javascript

Given this element:

```
<span class = "question_count">2.</span> Data de<input type="text" class="sq_field">
```

How to change the input type from text to date?

In order to get:

```
<span class = "question_count">2.</span> Data de<input type="date" class="sq_field">
```

Using JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm trying in the console, but not changing the input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByClassName('question_count')[0].type = 'date';
</script>
```

Comment: You DO realize this is the span right? `document.getElementsByClassName('question_count')`

Comment: Sure, the question is I want to change the input type from "text" to "date" and that isn't happening

Comment: but NO you are NOT since a span element cannot really have a "date" type as an input element can here.  You need your selector to select the input element

Comment: .getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("type", "date")